# Profile Edit Results in random errors

Tags: custom-object, force.com-sites, profile

I am trying to update public access setting for a newly created site. I have created a new object and and I would like to give all permission for this object.
To my surprise when I try to save object setting for this object on site user profile, I see below errors:

> error  Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Create Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Accounts
>   Permission Delete Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Accounts
>   Permission Edit Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Accounts
>   Permission Read Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Accounts
>   Permission Create Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Contact
>   Permission Delete Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Contact
>   Permission Edit Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Contact
>   Permission Read Contracts depends on permission(s): Read Contact

This object is nowhere linked to these objects. There is no lookup field on this object. Even when I tried to edit-save this object setting without making any change same error message was reported.

would be thankful for any pointers or help. Can it be some Salesforce Release issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is expected. It is not about how they are visibly link. Actually, these are dependent on each other permissions.

To see it in practical, do to any profile on UI, select any object and try to give "Modify All" without checking "View" and "Edit" permission. When you select the "Modify All", other permission checkbox will be checked automatically. This makes sense also, you must have view permission for the record to edit it.

Now, when you are manually changing it, you didn't give those pre-requisite permission which result into this error.

This is not a bug or release issue. Provide read/view access to Account object or remove all access from both Account and Contact object from that profile.

Comment: This is a custom object which is nowhere linked to any other object. Also I am facing this issue even if I click edit on setting and save it without any change.

Comment: Check permission for Contact and Account. @MukeshVerma There should be discrepancy

Comment: But why should I give permissions on Account or Contact when my force.com site is nowhere related to these objects. My site will work only with mentioned custom object which don't have any relation to any other custom or standard object.

Comment: Correct the permissions. It looks like that you have given some Permission to Contact object. @MukeshVerma

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. What is the relationship between his custom object and accounts, contacts or contracts (the error mentions both)? Why would giving permissions to accounts give permissions to his custom object?

Comment: @mkorman user should check once if there are any discrepancy with Account and Contact permissions. It is not said to give permission to these objects. Just check if some how permissions are given in wrong way.